# If $M_{n \times n} =\operatorname{span}\{A_1, A_2, ...,A_n\}$, show that $M_{n \times n}\operatorname{span}=\{ A_1^T,A_2^T,...,A_n^T\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

> If $M_{n\times n} =\operatorname{span}\{A_1, A_2, ...,A_n\}$, show that $M_{n\times n}=\operatorname{span}\{ A_1^T,A_2^T,...,A_n^T\}$.

**My Proof Attempt:**

Let $X,X^T \in M_{n \times n}$ then for $c_1, ...,c_n \in \mathbb{R}$ we have

\begin{align}
X^T &=c_1A_1+c_2A_2 +\dotsb+c_nA_n\\
X &=\left(c_1A_1+c_2A_2 +\dotsb+c_nA_n\right)^T\\
X &=c_1A_1^T+c_2A_2^T +\dotsb+c_nA_n^T
\end{align}

Hence we see that the set $\{A_1^T,A_2^T,...,A_n^T\}$ also spans $M_{n\times n}$. QED

Is this approach valid?

Comment: Yes, your approach is valid.